# Lifting a homotopy class $S^k\to X$ into a simplicial set $X$ which is not fibrant but satisfies some weaker horn filling condition

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $X$ be a connected simplicial set. If $X$ is an Kan complex and $k\geq 0$, then every element
$$
\tilde f\in\operatorname{Hom}_{Ho(sSet)}(S^k,X)
$$
of the homotopy classes from $S^k$ to $X$ lifts to a map $f\colon S^k\to X$ of simplicial sets. This is an abstract fact about model categories which may be applied since every simplicial set (and in particular $S^k$) is cofibrant and $X$ is fibrant.

Suppose $X$ satisfies the Kan condition only ''from a certain fixed $N$ on'', i.e. for all $n\geq N$, every diagram
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\Lambda^n_j &\to &X\\
\downarrow &&\\
\Delta^n
\end{array}
$$
obtains a lift $l\colon \Delta^n\to X$ (This is the usual Kan condition for $N=0$).

> Does there exist an $k>N$ such that every element $\tilde f$ in $\operatorname{Hom}_{Ho(sSet)}(S^k,X)$ can be lifted to $f\colon S^k\to X$, if $X$ satisfies the weaker condition above?

(I think that there exists a counterexample but I cannot think of one...)

Comment: What is $S^k$? Do you mean $\partial \Delta^{k+1}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I mean $\partial\Delta^{k+1}$.